# Error: sockopt.c:216:27: error: 'SCTP_NODELAY' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: apache

I am getting following error while trying to install httpd 2.0.49 from its source on ubuntu 12.04 machine.

```
sudo make 
...
...
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/satya/httpd-2.0.49/srclib/apr/network_io/unix'
/bin/bash /home/satya/httpd-2.0.49/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -g -O2 -pthread   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE   -I../../include -I../../include/arch/unix -I../../include/arch/unix  -c sockopt.c && touch sockopt.lo
sockopt.c: In function 'apr_socket_opt_set':
sockopt.c:216:27: error: 'SCTP_NODELAY' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I installed `lksctp` by executing `sudo apt-get install lksctp-tools` command and made few changes as suggested [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=11323&action=diff)

Even after doing this I am unable to compile the httpd and getting same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the configure script which assumes sctp is available even when it is not. This was fixed in later releases of 2.0.

Preferably, you should - if you want 2.0 - compile 2.0.65 instead.
Do however note that 2.0 is EOL (since 2013), so it is not officially supported by Apache anymore.

Comment: Thank you. I installed apache 2.0.65 without any error. But unable to install php 5.2.9. libphp5.so is not getting created after running following commands.     sudo ./configure --prefix=/home/satya/php5.2.9 --with-libdir=/lib/i386-linux-gnu --with-apxs2=/home/satya/apache2.0.65/bin/apxs --with-mysql             sudo make              sudo make install       It is creating libphp5.a and libphp5.la  Can you pl. let me know how this can be resolved. I need to use php5.2.9 only.